# Getting result from a query in a function and count the num_rows in Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter-3

My query in model :

```
public function infoReprob(){
    $tid = $this->input->get('tid');
    $query = $this->db->select('histprob.tid,histprob.ketprob,histprob.updated_at,otslm.lokasi')->from('histprob')->join('otslm', 'otslm.tid = histprob.tid')->where('histprob.tid', $tid)->get();
    return $query->result();
 }
```

Above query is used to result and work perfectly in a view in Ajax. But I need to count the result also, and I am trying to use the folowong in Controller :

```
function index(){
    $data['reprobs'] = count($this->m->infoReprob()); // USING COUNT
    $this->load->view('front/reprob_view', $data);
}
```

And call the variable inside my Javascript like :

```
<?php echo $reprobs; ?>
```

But it results : 0, even the actual num_rows is > 0.

Please help solve this.. Thank you so much

Comment: Have you tried the below answer and display the result by using `<?php echo $count; ?>` ? I think it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try following code

```
function index(){
    $data['result'] = $this->m->infoReprob(); // get RESULT
    $data['count'] = $this->m->infoReprob(1); // get COUNT
    $this->load->view('front/reprob_view', $data);
}
public function infoReprob($count=0){

    $tid = $this->input->get('tid');
    $query = $this->db->select('histprob.tid,histprob.ketprob,histprob.updated_at,otslm.lokasi')->from('histprob')->join('otslm', 'otslm.tid = histprob.tid')->where('histprob.tid', $tid)->get();
if ($count == 1)
        return $query->num_rows();
    else
        return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the replay, I changed the code as you suggested but still didn't get the expected result, but I can now solved my problem by using : _data.length_ inside my JS code that I just thought about. But still curious if I or somebody else need to count outside a JS. Thanks